# How to pass URL to get proper response in postman?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, backend, postgis

```
url = `${conn.get('spatialUsergeomUrl')}&LAYERS=` + username + '%3A' + datasetNme + '&SRS='+
       srs + '&BBOX=' + bbox + '&WIDTH=' + width + '&height=' + height + '&TRANSPARENT=' + 
       transparent + '&buffer=' + buffer
```

I am loading important components it returns a response. After that I want one postGis query
to be merged in above url in a format so that I may get proper response in request.
I am adding postgis query.

```
if (cql_filter !== null) {
  url = url + `&${geoDetails.get('GeometricFunctionBasedSingleWithQuery')}` +
  '&viewparams=comparisonValue%3A' + comparisonValue + 
  '%3BcomparisonOperator%3A' + comparisonOperator + '%3Bquery%3A' + cql_filter + 
  '%3BdatasetNme%3A' + datasetNme +'%3BcomparisonFunction%3A' + 
  comparisonFunction + '%3Busername%3A' + username
}
```

postgis query is

```
select distinct "%username%"."%datasetNme%".geom from "%username%"."%datasetNme%" where   ST_%comparisonFunction%("%username%"."%datasetNme%".geom) %comparisonOperator% %comparisonValue% and %query%
```

Comment: Why do you mix template literals with string concatenation?  You can continue the literal `\`${conn.get('spatialUsergeomUrl')}&LAYERS=${username}%3A${datasetNme}&SRS=${srs}&BBOX=${bbox}&WIDTH=${width}&height=${height}&TRANSPARENT=${transparent}&buffer=${buffer}\``

Comment: ok need to change this in url. Please how to pass user input to postgis query which is coming from GeometricFunctionBasedSingleWithQuery

Comment: input is in params in postman but i am getting response that is generated from above url, not the below url it keeps giving response generated from url that you wrote above

Comment: @mplungjan please help

Comment: @mplungjan sir please reply with the literal of this i need to use it.                                    url = url + `&${geoDetails.get('GeometricFunctionBasedSingleWithQuery')}` +
  '&viewparams=comparisonValue%3A' + comparisonValue + 
  '%3BcomparisonOperator%3A' + comparisonOperator + '%3Bquery%3A' + cql_filter + 
  '%3BdatasetNme%3A' + datasetNme +'%3BcomparisonFunction%3A' + 
  comparisonFunction + '%3Busername%3A' + username
}

Comment: You will have to wait for someone who understands your issue. I just did not like the mix of template literal and concatenation